# How to combine probability inequalities that are w.r.t. different random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities

Let $x$ and $z$ be two independent random variables.
Suppose I know the following two facts:

$P_z[f(x,z) < g(x)] > 1-\delta$ uniformly for all x;

$P_x[g(x) < h(x)] > 1-\delta_h$

How can I combine these to say something about $P_x[f(x,z) < h(x)] > 1-?$ with high probability ($1-\delta$) w.r.t. $z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rephrase both of these conditions in terms of the joint distribution $P(x,y)$.  The first is more tricky and required the independence assumption.  The second is trivial since it does not depend on $z$.  Once, you have this you know that they're both true with measure at least
$$
(1-\delta-\delta_h).
$$
Then you should be able to get the condition you desired, with any $(1-\delta-\delta_h)$ in place of both values at the end.  If you would like me to clarify or solve it fully I will do that later.  Just ask!

Comment: Thanks! I see - so we get that $P_{x,z}[f(x,z)<h(x)] >1-\delta-\delta_h$, which is a bound on the expectation $E_z[P_{x}[f(x,z)<h(x)]]$. I think we didn't need that the first inequality holds uniformly is that?

Comment: I agree, if the first bound w's in terms of (x,z), the same result would hold.  Do you have any more questions, or would you like to accept the answer?